# No protrusion into left margin with Nordic quotation marks with microtype, babel and csquotes

Tags: babel, punctuation, languages, microtype, csquotes

I want opening quotation marks to protrude into the left margin. And all is fine and dandy as long as I use English, but Nordic languages use `\textquotedblright` (”) for both opening and closing quotes. And I can't seem to make it work.

My best attempt was the commented line in the example below, but that doesn't seem to do anything at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[main=english, swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
% \SetProtrusion{encoding = *}{\textquotedblright = {1000, 1000}}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
  \noindent \enquote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}\\

  \selectlanguage{swedish}
  \noindent \enquote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\textquotedblright` does protrude into the margin, only less than you might expect. The reason why your settings don't have any effect is that settings for the Computer Modern Roman family exist, which take precedence. Therefore I suggest the following to overwrite the protrusion setting for the right double quote:

```
\LoadMicrotypeFile{cmr}
\SetProtrusion[ load = cmr-OT1 ]
  { encoding = OT1, family = cmr }
  {\textquotedblright = {1000, 1000}}
\SetProtrusion[ load = cmr-it-OT1 ]
  { encoding = OT1, family = cmr, shape = it }
  {\textquotedblright = {1000, 1000}}
\SetProtrusion[ load = cmr-sc-OT1 ]
  { encoding = OT1, family = cmr, shape = sc }
  {\textquotedblright = {1000, 1000}}
```

This first loads the file `mt-cmr.cfg`; the protrusion settings for the three shapes (upright, italics, small caps) will be loaded first, and overwritten for the right double quote (of course, if you're actually using a different encoding in your document, you would have to adapt it here).